# Get typed URL before redirecting me to offline page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So i use No-IP for DDNS for my customers. They have an offline page option I use. what the offline option does is if the device is offline or if they didn't enter the exact URL (like the port) it will redirect them to my offline page. What I want to do is when someone types mynoip.ddns.com It redirects them to my website offline page. I want to get the URL that was **originally** typed (mynoip.ddns.com) And they will do a troubleshooting step and they can click on there DDNS Domain mynoip.ddns.com:8090 or whatever there DDNS is from No-IP site. Something similar from (`var old URL = document.referrer;`) I use WordPress. Assuming PHP won't do the trick. JavaScrip and anything else Wordpress allows.

Comment: Add some code snippet?

Comment: @hack4mer Please elaborate or refer me?